# React Native: How to navigate from app.js

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

When click notification then I want to navigate notification tab or any other screen from `app.js`. Is there any way?

I have used firebase cloud function for sending notification.
Here is my app.js

```
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        // const {title, body} = notificationOpen.notification;

        /*
         * To navigate notification tab instead of TimeLine tab
         * */
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications');
        /*
         * Or navigate other screen like ProfileView
         * */
        // this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileView');
      });

    const notificationOpen = await firebase
      .notifications()
      .getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      /*
       * To navigate notification tab instead of TimeLine tab
       * */
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications');
      /*
       * Or navigate other screen like ProfileView
       * */
      // this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileView');
    }
```

Error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')`

Comment: Can you share entire app.js file in your post?

Comment: @ridvanaltun, Thank you for your reply. app.js not taking here cause here 504 line of code. It shows error: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." Here is github link (https://github.com/rkobhi512/ContainerApp/blob/master/app.js)

Comment: Well.. Can you share app.js with gist or pastebin maybe? You don't need to edit your post just leave a comment.

Comment: @ridvanaltun, Please (https://pastebin.com/433vTTDq)